# Flutter web with Hive data base

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-hive

I developed demo **web** app with **Flutter** and upload it on my server and I used **[Hive database](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)** to store some data on web app.

Recently I found that when I open web app and store some data on it,
if I use different browser again I can't see the previously stored data,
it seems that Hive on Flutter web will store data somewhere on client side cache.

I have 3 questions now:

- Where is the location of hive database and how can I access it manually?
- How can I fix this problem and store data on my server with Flutter web that every user could see the same data?
- Should I use Dart for server side to achieve this goal? If yes, where can I start and find good documents?

[image]

[image]

Here is my code to save and load data:

```
void _initHiveDB() async {
    
        if (_isDBInited) {
          return;
        }
    
        if(!kIsWeb){
          final documentsDirectory = await Path_Provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          Hive.init(documentsDirectory.path);
        }
    
        Hive.registerAdapter(ComplaintModelAdapter(), 0);
        _isDBInited = true;
    
      }



    Future<bool> saveNewComplaint(ComplaintModel complaintModel)async{
    
        try{
          if(_complaintBox==null||!_complaintBox.isOpen){
            _complaintBox = await Hive.openBox('Complaints');
          }
          else{
            _complaintBox = Hive.box('Complaints');
          }
          _complaintBox.add(complaintModel);
          return true;
        }
        catch(exc){
          
          return false;
        }
    
      }


    Future<List<ComplaintModel>> loadAllComplaints() async {
    try{
          if(_complaintBox==null||!_complaintBox.isOpen){
            _complaintBox = await Hive.openBox('Complaints');
          }
          else{
            _complaintBox = Hive.box('Complaints');
          }
          //Box<ComplaintModel> complaintBox = await Hive.openBox('Complaints');
          //Box<ComplaintModel> complaintBox = await Hive.box('Complaints');
          List<ComplaintModel> complaints = _complaintBox.values.toList();
          return complaints;
        }
        catch(exc){
          return null;
        }}
```

Comment: HiveDB is a local database that uses the platform's filesystem in mobile Platforms. In browsers it uses the [IndexedDB of the browser](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/more/browser?id=browser-support). So you cannot share data among all users. To achieve that you can use Firebase's Cloud Firestore as a backend database.

Answer (score 1):

Hive does its job correctly, it is an embedded database and must have different databases for different browsers. If you need this information to be shared in the cloud you should look for another type of database. A cloud database would be the solution. There are free solutions among the google tools for example, or to create your API connecting to a Database SQL for example.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why you would want to use hive in that way, which is probably because you love how fast it is. That is however only so because it's embedded. If you wish to achieve that speed while still using it in as embedded, you would have to sync your data with a cloud or network database so that each browser can update their data from the cloud db in the background and the client browsers can get the updates. A simple mysql database would be fine although you would have to work around sql to nosql and back. It's some sort of Decentralized approach. I have implemented it before and it works nicely.